# When did it become openly known that Wilson supported the Balfour Declaration?

Tags: united-states, world-war-one, israel, arab

According to this source he agreed with the declaration about one month before it was published.

http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1878450?uid=3738984&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21104407900711

My question is was it known to the Arabs that the United States supported the declaration when it was published? If not, when did this become known?

Answer (score 2):

On August 31, 1918, President Wilson wrote a letter to Rabbi [Stephen Samuel Wise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Samuel_Wise) which referred to the Balfour Declaration and said in part:

> I welcome an opportunity to express the satisfaction I have felt in
>   the progress of the Zionist movement in the United States...

This letter was published a few days later, September 5th, 1918, in the New York Times.

Comment: A decent answer. However, one could argue that personal correspondence to a Jewish Rabbi does not translate to open knowledge in the Arab world.

Comment: @T.E.D. It was published in the NYT.

Comment: NYT is just a local rag, after all... :)